# angular : Origin http://localhost not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

I'm calling an REST API on a different domain with the following code from my angularjs web app, but I'm seeing the following error in my console. Any help here is much appreciated as this is delaying my delivery badly.

Errors:
Origin http://localhost not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

Code:

$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

```
        $http.post(this.urlBase + '/Product/PullBasket/', $httpParamSerializerJQLike(cart)).then(function success(result) {         
            if (result.status == 200) {
                Logger.info("Pull Request Id : " + result.data);
            }
            else {
                Logger.info("Error is pull request : " + result.data);
            }
        }, function failure(result) {
            Logger.fatalException("Error is pull request.");
        });
```

Comment: So how is the url base different than the address in your address bar?

Comment: urlbase is the url of the rest service that is picked up from the config file. The rest service is hosted on a different server.

Comment: So the error is correct that it is a cross domain call.

Comment: Yeah, I know that it is throwing the correct error :) I'm looking for some resolution steps.

Comment: So you need to enable CORS on the api like the error and the answer below states.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't own the API I'm just the consumer of it. Is there are client side that I can do. I've tried the solution provided http://enable-cors.org/, but it didn't help I'm still getting Access denied when I do  xhr.open('POST', this.urlBase + '/Product/PullBasket/');

Comment: Well than you would need to use a serverside proxy to get the data.

Comment: I found the solution from the http://enable-cors.org/, but the only change is the in contrast to what mentioned in the link to use XDomainRequest() for IE, I've used XMLHttpRequest(), now my only issue is that though my network trace shows the call is successful and responding me back with the response body. The xhr response object says it is empty may be because it is just sending the response as plain text which I assume xhr doesn't support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty strange, but seems related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

if so, you'll have to set up http://enable-cors.org/